# Using Python 2.7 To Stream Video In A Web Browser.

Tags: python-2.7, video, web, streaming, adobe

This is my first time asking a question on SO, so I'll jump right in and hopefully I'm doing things correctly.  I've searched through Google and through the boards and while there are resources on streaming, they don't seem to give me the answer to my question.

The short version: I would like to setup a python27 handler to stream video to a web browser. We currently have a way of doing this with PHP using Adobe FMS on a series of Linux servers.

Long Version: My company uses an internal web streaming page that's currently setup using PHP. We want to step away from PHP as the handler for this and we've figured that Python would be up to the task of this. My problem? I'm not a web developer. I don't know the first thing about integrating py files in html.

I've written software in Windows and in Linux before and I've played with video using PyMedia (nothing serious there). Additionally, I've found resources saying to use Flask to set up streaming but my brain cannot make heads or tails of it and it really doesn't *click* for me. If that makes sense.

Has anyone undertaken such a project, and if they have can they suggest a website, tutorial or article that can help in greater detail?

I can clarify or answer any questions that you may have to help answer this question in further detail.

As I understand it:

1. HTML would give the user the front end and media player to interact with.
2. The user will click on a playlist item and that will send an input through the python handler to begin processing video from our FMS cache.
3. The user sits backs, drinks a Capri Sun and enjoys the very boring lectures and award ceremonies that we host.

Thank you all very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial and its correspoding github page helps noobs like us to do this very easily at least in the LAN. For how to stream on the internet, even I'm trying to find out. Supposedly, it involves port forwarding.

http://www.chioka.in/python-live-video-streaming-example/

Just download the zip and follow the steps:

Install Python dependencies: 
    cv2, flask. (wish that pip install works like a charm)

Run:
    python main.py

Navigate the browser to the local webpage.

Comment: it just support one user connection